# Value of environment variable does not passed into field of application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes

There is some env definition of value in application.properties as

```
AUTH0_URL=${MY_AUTH0_URL:}
```

i.e. expected value from MY_AUTH0_URL environment variable , if environment not defined - take empty string

Environment variable provided via configmap as following

```
- name: MY_AUTH0_URL
    value: "http://someurl"
```

But when running application , the value of MY_AUTH0_URL environment does not passed into value AUTH0_URL from application.properties .

In code the value as below

```
 @Value(value = "${AUTH0_URL}")
 private String auth0Url;
```

What can be possible reason ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your config map file, all individual properties should be defined in `data` tab. Example

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: demo
data:
  MY_AUTH0_URL: http://someurl
```

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.0.0.M2/multi/multi__configmap_propertysource.html)